# Javascript: Check if a twitter tweet exists

Tags: javascript

I have like to use javascript to check if a tweet is still available or it has already been deleted.

If a tweet is deleted, it will show a page like this:

https://twitter.com/xgamecrawlx/status/1296409174503493632

With the text:  Sorry, that page doesn’t exist!

So maybe I need to read the page and if this string "Sorry, that page doesn’t exist!" is found, it means it has been deleted.

Any suggestion or hint on how I could do this using javascript?  I would like to avoid using Twitter API if possible...

Comment: You probably want to do this through the Twitter API: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/post-and-engage/overview

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you need: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/labs/tweets-and-users/quick-start/get-tweets. Assuming you use node.js, you could use some library to easen the burden of making http requests, such as `superagent` on npm.

As far as I know, twitter doesn't provide any recent or well-maintained module on npm, which is a pity in your case

Comment: Do you think it is possible without using the API?

Comment: I am afraid this is the most straightforward and easy-to-use approach, which will NOT end in your IPs being banned at some point in the future. Twitter also has some internal APIs, but while they are available (at this point in time), there is no guarantee they will work in the future and they are not documented, so you will pretty much have to reverse-engineer, how the authentication works there. You'd be much better off using official and documented API.

Comment: If you really want to avoid API, you should check the browser console and work with the JSON file network request to the following address: ```https://api.twitter.com/2/timeline/conversation/1296409174503493632.json``` (included here without http queries). However, you will exceed rate limit in 2 or 3 requests, I have tried